# Why pushing my project gives me a nested repository

Tags: github, nested, push

I want to push a full project to github where i have a project folder that contains a front-end folder and a back-end folder. Like this:

```
- Project Folder
 |- FrontEnd folder
 |- BackEnd folder
```

I tried pushing it but i makes a Nested repository.

Comment: what do you mean by "nested repository" (or, do you mean submodule)?

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean.